# Custom option in EntityType (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have this code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('client_id', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:WebClient',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er
                ->createQueryBuilder('w_client')
                ->where('w_client.is_removed = 0');
        },
        'choice_label' => function ($w_client) {
            return $w_client->getCompanyName();
        },
    ])
->getForm();
```

How can I add custom static item in Select to get this result?

```
<select>
    <option value="add">Add</option>
    <optgroup label="Group">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncbT0.png)

Comment: Do you want to customize a selectbox or do you want two form types: one to select exiting options and one to add a new option?

Comment: What do you mean with "Static element"?

Comment: @sam-mumm Yes exactly.

Comment: @balzacLeGeek Added manually, not through Entity.

Answer (score 2):

An `EntityType` field is expecting all the choices to be an instance of that entity, so it's not a good idea to add a custom option that is a string value. You could of course add the option dynamically with JS on the client side after the form is rendered, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Instead, I would use a `ChoiceType` and manually build the chocies:

```php
$choices = [
    'add' => 'Add'
];

foreach ($er->findBy(['is_removed' => 0]) as $client) {
    $choices[$client->getId()] = $client->getCompanyName();
}

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('client_id', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $choices
    ])
->getForm();
```

In your example output, you show the choices being grouped. You can do this with a multi dimensional array:

```php
foreach ($er->findBy(['is_removed' => 0]) as $client) {
    if (!array_key_exists($client->getGroup()) {
        $choices[$client->getGroup()] = [];
    }
    $choices[$client->getGroup()][$client->getId()] = $client->getCompanyName();
}
```

*assuming `WebClient` has a `$group` property, you can obviously change this to whatever you want to group by*